# Modify method parameters the same way in many methods

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, wildcard

is there a straight forward way to **modify every parameter of a method** without having to code this within the method?
i'm using storedprocedures as database layer and the task is to offer wildcard usage for the application which provides a **'*' wildcard** and that has to be **changed to the '%' sql wildcard**.
Having an WildcardAttribute like this would be great:

```
[WildcardAttribute('*', '%')]
[WildcardAttribute('?', '_')]
SearchMethod( s) // -> value of s: *
{
   InvokeSPROC( s) // -> value of s:  %
}
```

instead of :

```
  SearchMethod( s) // -> value of s: *
    {
       InvokeSPROC( s.Replace("*", "%").Replace("?", "_")) 
    }
```

Maling this modification in the sproc is not an option..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use an AOP framework like PostSharp to do that. https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net

For an example see http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator. Section Accessing parameters

> It's also possible to modify the parameter values inside your aspect methods. All you need to do is modify the value of the item in the Arguments collection. Remember that all items in the Arguments collection are object types so you will need to be careful with how you change values. If the value you are modifying was originally a string, you will want to ensure it stays a string type

There are more AOP framework for .Net, so you could read about them.

By the way, how does your code `InvokeSPROC` looks like? Can't you replace the characters there?

EDIT:
If it is too complicated you can either create a method for it or maybe write an extension method like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SanitizeForStoredProcedure(this string pattern)
    {
        return pattern.Replace("*", "%").Replace("?", "_");    
    }
}
```

You can then call it using

```
SearchMethod( s) // -> value of s: *
{
   InvokeSPROC( s.SanitizeForStoredProcedure() ) // -> value of s:  %
}
```

Comment: the AOP stuff seems to be to complicated for my requirement, so i will enhance the SPROC invovation methods.

Comment: @DanielDevo It takes a little time, yes. But it is powerful. But I've updated my answer with an alternative using an extension method. You can also create a simple method that does the same as long as you make sure you only need to modify one piece of code to change the behavior as intended. More about extension methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx